# FFMpeg returns error: Unrecognized option 'master_pl_name'

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, laravel-7, ffmpeg-php

I used this command (described at the processing message bellow) on my application several times before and always worked well. Now returns that error.

```
'/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-threads' '12' '-i' 
'/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/videos/videos_disk/a3.mp4' '-map' '0' '-vcodec' 'libx264' 
'-b:v' '500k' '-g' '48' '-hls_playlist_type' 'vod' '-hls_time' '10' '-hls_segment_filename' 
'/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_0_500_%05d.ts' '-master_pl_name' 
'master_playlist_guide_0.m3u8' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:a' '128k' 
'/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_0_500.m3u8' '-map' '0' '-vcodec' 
'libx264' '-b:v' '1500k' '-g' '48' '-hls_playlist_type' 'vod' '-hls_time' '10' '-hls_segment_filename' 
'/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_1_1500_%05d.ts' '-master_pl_name' 
'master_playlist_guide_1.m3u8' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:a' '128k' 
'/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_1_1500.m3u8' '-map' '0' '-vcodec' 
'libx264' '-b:v' '3000k' '-g' '48' '-hls_playlist_type' 'vod' '-hls_time' '10' '-hls_segment_filename' 
'/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_2_3000_%05d.ts' '-master_pl_name' 
'master_playlist_guide_2.m3u8' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:a' '128k' 
'/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_2_3000.m3u8'
```

```
(single line:) '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-threads' '12' '-i' '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/videos/videos_disk/a3.mp4' '-map' '0' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-b:v' '500k' '-g' '48' '-hls_playlist_type' 'vod' '-hls_time' '10' '-hls_segment_filename' '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_0_500_%05d.ts' '-master_pl_name' 'master_playlist_guide_0.m3u8' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:a' '128k' '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_0_500.m3u8' '-map' '0' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-b:v' '1500k' '-g' '48' '-hls_playlist_type' 'vod' '-hls_time' '10' '-hls_segment_filename' '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_1_1500_%05d.ts' '-master_pl_name' 'master_playlist_guide_1.m3u8' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:a' '128k' '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_1_1500.m3u8' '-map' '0' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-b:v' '3000k' '-g' '48' '-hls_playlist_type' 'vod' '-hls_time' '10' '-hls_segment_filename' '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_2_3000_%05d.ts' '-master_pl_name' 'master_playlist_guide_2.m3u8' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:a' '128k' '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/public/test_2_3000.m3u8':
```

This is the error returned:

```
 ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Unrecognized option 'master_pl_name'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

I`ve reinstalled the ffmpeg, also tested in a virtual machine and the same error happens.

Live server: CentOS 7 / Apache2 / PHP-fpm 7.3;
Virtual machine: Ubuntu 20.04 / nginx / PHP-fpm 7.4.5

I really have no clue about what to do about it now.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out: the issue was the ffmpeg version. I compiled a new one with the latest version from ffmpeg.org (4.3.1), and it's all fine now.